# Silverlight Code Obfuscation

Tags: silverlight, obfuscation

I'm looking for recommendations of any free tools available for Silverlight code obfuscation.  The professional version of obfuscator supports Silverlight, but the community edition of Obfuscator does not.

Obfuscar from Google Code requires manual specification of every item that shouldn't be obfuscated, so every control and property referenced in XAML must be manually listed.  There's no option to not obfuscate names of any public types and members.  Even if I manually specify every public class and member, I don't know yet whether there are any other Silverlight issues lurking.

I'm not interested in starting another discussion about the wisdom of code obfuscation, or the lack thereof.

Comment: If you find a tool that renames variables to a1, a2 etc. Then I don't see why it wouldn't work with SL.

Comment: Very good question.  I would like the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

.NET Reactor is a waste of money. There are automatic unpacking tools for almost all versions of the program and the author doesn't answer emails. During my evaluations and testing of a lot of obfuscators I came up with the following list:

- CodeFort - Very promising. Missing some features at the time of writing but author is already working on them and very responsive to emails. Cheap in comparison to others as well.
- CLISecure - Good support and product but very very pricey
- SmartAssembly - Protected program crashed also deobfuscators available but they change small things now and then to thwart them so Its a good choice.
- 9Rays - Hardly obfuscated anything. (I checked the settings) So waste of money.
- DeapSea - More expensive then CodeFort and fewer features.
- CryptoObfuscator - Mid range pricing and feature packed. But I'm not sure how strong the protection is. At one point it was very easy to crack according to some posts. Not sure if that's is still the case.

Comment: I wanted to provide an update with what I eventually went with. Babel .NET obfuscator (http://www.babelfor.net/) it is by far the best of all of them not only feature packed but also cheap and not locked to a single computer like all the others are. Downside is it has no GUI and this is the reason I overlooked it at first but It really is easy to use and one of the few that did not cause my application to crash.

Comment: +1 for Babel .NET. Worked out of the box and the application did not crash

Comment: Babel .NET works out of the box and it didnt crash for me either.. then again it didn't protect my code very well either, Easily decompiled it.

Answer (score 2):

I am excited to tell you, that you no longer have to manually exclude types and members from obfuscation of Silverlight assemblies. In fact, you don't have to exclude anything at all.

CodeFort is the first obfuscator ever to introduce XAML and BAML renaming. This means that references to types and members inside of the XAML and BAML code will be updated in sync with the rest of the obfuscation - and by doing that there's no need to leave large portions of the code unprotected, as all other obfuscators do today.

If you want to take a look for yourself, go download the CodeFort Free Edition from our website:
http://codefort.org/download

Hope this helps,

Christian

codefort.org

Comment: Christian. I bought your professional edition. But the software won't even activate. It gives me a key and asks me to go to codefort.org/my to get activation code. But I cannot go to that page as it asks me for a user id and password which I was not provided with.

Comment: I just tried the free version of CodeFort. Worked beautifully! Did this after failing to obfuscate with Dotobfuscator, Confuser, and Obfuscator Skater. And having false free leads to Eazfuscator.NET and Babel.

Comment: Activation is a pain with codefort, and does not work on win8/8.1, otherwise it is a great product.

Answer (score 1):

The version of Dotfuscator Community Edition that will ship with Visual Studio 2010 will support obfuscation of both Silverlight 2 and Silverlight 3 assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/babelobfuscator/ the free and cool one for now :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a good & free obfuscator for Silverlight so far. Here is a nice review of some cheap obfuscators: 
http://www.olsonsoft.com/blogs/stefanolson/post/Selecting-an-obfuscator-for-Silverlight.aspx. 
The author choosed .NET Reactor as favorit obfuscator.

Answer (score 1):

PreEmptive Solutions is in the final phase of beta testing the latest Dotfuscator release that extends protection beyond the Silverlight assembly and into the XAML resources too. (This kind of support is already in production for WPF/BAML). This has three benefits; more of your assembly is protected, your XAML is protected, and you save time since configuration is now much simpler (no more exclusions).

If you are interesting in being a beta candidate, email me (sebastian@preemptive.com) and I will have our support team send you credentials. Please keep in mind, this is beta – there are no fees – and you will have access to our support – but you cannot use this version for any production work.

The only software requirements are .NET 1.1 or higher and Silverlight 2 or higher. (Yes - test this inside Windows Mobile 7, Windows Azure, ...)

A few other things to consider:

• Analytics (feature and usage tracking) can also be injected post-compile

• The analytics also support the Expression Blend Silverlight Analytics Framework (allowing both design-time web analytics and post-compile- time instrumentation in one).

• Dotfuscator consumes XAP files rather than assemblies and re-signs them automatically making your builds that much simpler.

• Dotfuscator is also an efficient “pruner” shrinking you Silverlight apps along the way…

For more information on our “universal Silverlight support”, see our TechEd announcement at http://www.preemptive.com/news-events/press-releases/307